# Regex List All \w

Tags: .net, regex

In .NET is there a way to enumerate all the values for \w?

As for why I am parsing words from unknown files.  Will come across some files that use embedding that are nothing but non standard.  See sample below

"PK!RýëÙ*[Content_Types].xml ¢( Ì?ÍNã0?÷Hó?·£Æ530Ì¨)?Y!@?ycß6VÛò5Ð¾=7)T*­""""áM«üø?ïºÕ?Ïä|ÙØâ" "ï*&Ê1+À)¯?Wìÿý¿Ñ+0I§¥õ*¶dçÓoG?ûU,hµÃ?Õ)???£ª¡?Xú??Ì|ld¢Ë8çAª???O¹ò.K£Ôj°éä/Ìä£MÅå?n¯I?cÅÅú½Öªb2k?LÊ??~g2ò³?Q ½zlHºÄAj¬RcË  9Æ;H?CÆwzF°ØÏôuª?Vv`X??ßiôÚ'Oõºî?~?h4·2¦kÙÐì|iù³?ïå~?¾[ÓmQÙHãÞ¸÷øw/#ï¾ÄÀ í|pO?ãL8~dÂñ3??L8N3áø? ÇY&¿3áã\@rIT?K¤?\2Uäª?T¹ÄªÈ%WÅW+Ð©9:i¯?[

I think this was a output to printer file.

Need to somehow eliminate what I am calling trash words.  It does not need to be perfect.  The plan is to mark documents with trash words not included in the index so the user has an easy means for manual review.

What I may end of doing is counting from a list of safe chars (a,b,c,...).  Like it must have one safe char or more than 1/2 safe chars to keep.  Like I want to keep Café.  Trash words tend to be all trash.  This is a trash word ª'_LLýú that happens to have some safe chars.

At this point I am evaluating the battle field.

The nature of the business is may intentionally get sent trash files.

In case anyone cares I went with

`rSafeChar = new Regex(@"[-_'@A-Za-z0-9]");`

Toying with `safeCharCount > unsafeCharCount` or `safeCharCount >= unsafeCharCount`

Comment: just curious, why would one want to do that?

Comment: What do you mean enumarate all the values ? \w is equivalent to "[A-Za-z0-9_]"

Comment: There are 48745 chars  `\w` matches in the range of 0-65535 (all possible utf-16 chars). Are they all valid? (74%)

Comment: @L.B that is exactly what I am trying to my arms around.  Just knowing that number is 48725 tells me a lot.

Comment: @Blam, What I did for this: I downloaded Apache Tika and IKVM. Converted the java code to .Net using IKVM and made Tika to try to extract the text content of a file(any type of file) which can be used to index the file. If you are interested, give it a try.

Comment: @L.B  In pure .NET I did an (char)i and got 47992 match to /w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check what can be matched by \w one could use a string containing the whole ascii table and use the following regex :

```
(?:(?<wmatch>\w)*(?<wnotmatch>[^\w]*))*
```

The resulting groups should contain the list of characters matched and not matched by \w.

Here is an example :

```
private void TestMatch()
{
  string ascii = "abcdef0934+_!1@_$14-195djsjfke1058446541";
  Regex r = new Regex(@"(?:(?<wmatch>\w)*(?<wnotmatch>[^\w]*))*");
  Match m = r.Match(ascii);
  if (m.Success)
  {
    string msg = "\\w matches :";
    foreach (Capture cap in m.Groups["wmatch"].Captures)
    {
      msg += cap.Value + ", ";
    }
    msg += Environment.NewLine + "\\w does not match: ";
    foreach (Capture cap in m.Groups["wnotmatch"].Captures)
    {
      msg += cap.Value + ", ";
    }
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
  }
}
```

Shows :

```
\\w matches :a, b, c, d, e, f, 0, 9, 3, 4, _, 1, _, 1, 4, 1, 9, 5, d, j, s, j, f, k, e, 1, 0, 5, 8, 4, 4, 6, 5, 4, 1,  
\\w does not match: +, !, @, $, -, "
```